# C# WinForms use instance of class in all Forms w/o passing everytime

Tags: c#, class

I'm a newbie and im pretty sure its a dumb question but i couldnt find a thread which is solving exactly my problem or im simply to much of a newbie to understand, i dont know.

**My Problem**:
I got a Login Form, when the login was successfully i create an instance of my "User" class and pass it to the mainForm. From now on i have to pass the object or the userid to any other form.

Is it possible to create the instance ONE time at the login and use it WITHOUT creating or passing it everytime?

Hope my question is clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a single form that is always open, or does your application rely on users moving from form to form (with the unused ones getting closed).  The answer to the question your asked is "Yes".  How you should do it depends on how your application works

Comment: From a design point of view, passing it around is often the best alternative, the other options being storing it in a static class or property somewhere.

Comment: Thank you guys, i guess i found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easiest way to achieve that is putting your class in place where all forms can see it.Like Program.cs

```
static class Program 
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new IzborPretrage());
    }
    public static MyClass GlobalStuff { get; set; }
}
```

You can then set it like:

```
Program.GlobalStuff = yourClassInstance;
```

**Another way would be to create a singleton class:**
You can find example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650316(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)